# Formatting C++ Output two Columns different Justification

Tags: c++, formatting, output, cout

This is my code:

```
cout << fixed <<showpoint<<setprecision(2);
cout << setw(10) << left << "Employee:"<< right << setw(9) << name <<endl;
cout << setw(10) << left << "Hours Worked:"<< right << setw(9) << hrWork <<endl; 
cout << setw(10) << left << "Hourly Rate:"<< right << setw(9) << hrRate <<endl;
cout << setw(10) << left  << "Total Wages:"<< right << setw(9) << tWages <<endl << endl;

cout << left << setw(10) << "Federal Withholding:"<< right << setw(9) << fedW <<endl;
cout << left << setw(10) << "State Withholding:"<< right << setw(9) << staW <<endl;
cout << left << setw(10) << "Hospitalization:"<< right << setw(9) << hosp <<endl;
cout << left << setw(10) << "Union Dues:"<< right << setw(9) << uniDues <<endl;
cout << left << setw(10) << "Total Deductions:"<< right << setw(9) << tDeduc <<endl;
cout << left << setw(10) << "Net Pay:"<< right << setw(9) << netP <<endl;
```

This is my current output (I've tried set(w) and justification several ways. This is the closest I could get):

```
Employee:   Anthony
Hours Worked:    20.00
Hourly Rate:     8.75
Total Wages:   175.00

Federal Withholding:    31.50
State Withholding:     7.88
Hospitalization:    25.65
Union Dues:     3.50
Total Deductions:    68.53
Net Pay:     106.47
```

This is what I was aiming at (two columns one justified to the left and the other to the right):

```
Employee:             Anthony
Hours Worked:           20.00
Hourly Rate:             8.75
Total Wages:           175.00

Federal Withholding:    31.50
State Withholding:       7.88
Hospitalization:        25.65
Union Dues:              3.50
Total Deductions:       68.53
Net Pay:               106.47
```

How can I do this? Thank you

Comment: Can you please format your expected output into columns so we know what you are expecting? Your question says two columns but it appears you have more than two columns of data.

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have said columns. The third section of code contains what I was expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most strings on the left side are longer than 10 characters, use e,g, setw(25).

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you